# UIView height change creates extra space on bottom

Tags: ios

I would like to create a Facebook Messenger-like emoticon bar above the keyboard, but I'd like to slide the toolbar open and show the emoticons above the input field. Now I'm changing the height of this `UIView` (set as `accessoryInputView`), but the items inside also go up.

I have added constraints to keep the items locked to the bottom of the UIView, but this is not working either. I perform layoutIfNeeded on the toolbar to try to fit the constraints again, but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess, you must have constraints pulling them up somehow. This could be because you specified them or because you did not specify enough constraints and they have been added automatically by the system. Try adding a top constraint for the emoticons that is >=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, when you double clic on a constraint you can change it's relation property from "Equal" to "Greater than or Equal" or "Less than or Equal".

If you force you view to a certain height, even if you add constraints it won't get bigger or smaller ;)

An other option is to change your top space / bottom space priority constraint to 1001 but it's far less "clean" if I may ;).

Hope it fixes your issue.